# Split C string into tokens using sscanf

Tags: c, string, c99

I'm trying to split a string into tokens but somewhat recursively. I am trying to parse:

```
"content=0&website=Google"
```

so that I have a way to take out the parameters and values. If I try `strtok` I end up destroying the string I want to parse twice. So I tried

```
char *contents = "content=0&website=Google"
char arg[100];
char value[100];
sscanf(contents, "%s&%s", arg, value);
```

as a first pass, hoping to parse `arg` again, but it fails, and `arg` contains the entire string. I tried using `"%s\&%s"` thinking `&` was a reserved word, but no luck there.

Help!

Edit:

This was my strtok hack:

```
static void readParams(char * string, char * param, char * value) {
    printf("This is the string %s\n",string);
    char * splitted = strtok (string,"=");

    while (splitted != NULL)
    {
        printf("This is the string %s\n",splitted);
        splitted = strtok (NULL, "=");
        // Then do some saving to param and value
    }
}
char * splitted = strtok (contents,"&");
int counter = 0;

while (splitted != NULL)
{
    char * t_str = strdup(splitted);
    readParams(t_str, param, value);
    splitted = strtok (NULL, "&");
}
```

but it doesn't work because splitted's `strtok` at the end becomes gobbldygook.

Comment: So save a copy of the string before you call `strtok()`.

Comment: @S.O users I my perception this is a very nice question. In addition to predicting other methods it will be better if someone reason for why the sscanf(contents, "%s&%s", arg, value); doesn't work

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT like I said in my answer, asking `scanf` to scan for `%s` causes it to scan up to the next whitespace. So it won't stop on an ampersand.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a solution that seems to work:

```
char *contents = "content=0&website=Google";
char arg[100] = {0};
char value[100] = {0};
sscanf(contents, "%[^&]&%s", arg, value);
printf("%s\n%s\n", arg, value);
```

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` is more primitive than you seem to think — `%s` will match everything up to the next whitespace. Your best solution is probably to stick with `strtok` but throw it only content you've `strdup`ed from the authoritative original.

Comment: When I try to abstract the sub-parsing into a new function passing in a strduped version of the split, it fails. Why is this? I've added code to the above to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend something similar to the following:

```
char t_str[100];
strncpy(t_str, contents, 100);
//now strtok() on t_str, original contents will be preserved
```